# Embed Jquery into html or seperate file?

Tags: jquery, html

Is it better to put J Query directly into html or in a separate file and which one is more conventional?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Comment: generally a separate file is most common practice. but is it "better" in terms of performance, no.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's better to keep your jQuery in a separate file. It makes your HTML code more organised.